# SQL Server specific random date using NEWID() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert a specific start date for my products.
It should be between 48 hours ago and now.

This is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW getNewID AS 
         SELECT         
         DATEADD(MILLISECOND, (ROUND((999 * NEWID()), 0)), 
         DATEADD(SECOND, (ROUND((((DATEDIFF(SECOND, (DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())),
         (GETDATE())))-1) * NEWID()), 0)), (DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())))) 
         AS new_id
```

This view will return a random date between the ranges specified. The function below will return the `NEWID()` because SQL won't let me use `NEWID()`'s in a function.

However, the view above will give me an error :

> the uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int.

This won't happen if I use RAND(), but this will give me the same value for all the rows I insert (I want to use this for my conversion script).

```
CREATE FUNCTION randomID()
RETURNS uniqueidentifier
AS BEGIN
   RETURN (SELECT new_id FROM getNewID)
END
```

Maybe some of you have encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a number between 0 and 48*60*60*1000 (48 hours ago)
like this:

```
abs(checksum(newid())) % (48*60*60*1000)
```

And use `DATEADD`

```
SELECT dateadd(millisecond, 0 - abs(checksum(newid())) % (48*60*60*1000), getdate())
```